# Multiple Updates on Views causing Locks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

We have a 10 minutes schedule job which runs a stored procedure every 20 minutes. The stored procedure has multiple update statements in it. This process usually cause locks and affects system performance. I have notices that `UPDATE` statements are running on views.

Can anyone explain is there any difference between executing updating on a table vs. on a view?

I was just thinking that updating on view might be causing locks.

Also any suggestions to avoid locking on updates.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Example `UPDATE` queries. The stored procedure has 12 such update queries.

```
UPDATE View1
SET col1 = CAST((dbo.gettimeremainingminutes(getdate(), dbo.f_UTCToLocalTime(col2)) / 1440) as INTEGER)
WHERE View2 IS NOT NULL 
  AND [Status] = 0 
  AND IsActive = 1

UPDATE View1
SET col1 = ISNULL(col1, 0) + CAST((dbo.function1(dbo.f_UTCToLocalTime(col2), getdate()) * 60) AS INTEGER),
    col3 = ISNULL(col3, 0) + CAST((dbo.function1(dbo.f_UTCToLocalTime(col2), getdate())) AS INTEGER)
WHERE [Status] = 0
```

Comment: **ANY** update operations will create **update locks** .....

Comment: These locks put our system down and the problem is we need to run these updates every 20 minutes. We can schedule them out of working hours.

Comment: The locks **are necessary** and if designed correctly, they're **not a problem** at all ... SQL Server will only lock **those rows** that are actually being updated. As long as you don't update excessively many rows at once, you should be just fine

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with example Update queries. They are very simple I can't see any thing complicated there other then calling a function for each row. And Stored Procedure have 12 such update statements.

Comment: You cannot typically update a **view** - do these views have `INSERT OF UPDATE` triggers?